# message sent to deallocated instance on accelerometer

Tags: ios, objective-c

when I run my application e touch close button for return i get this error:

```
*** -[TrackingSamplesViewController accelerometer:didAccelerate:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1889c400
```

I use accellerometer in this point:

in viewDidLoad:

```
UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
accel.delegate = self;
accel.updateInterval = 1.0f/60.0f;
```

and define:

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)acel didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration {

if (acceleration.z < (-0.9 - 0.1 ))
{

    wv.hidden =NO;
}

if (acceleration.z > (-0.9 + 0.1 )) {

    wv.hidden =YES;
}
}
```

someone can help me? thanks

Comment: What is `TrackingSamplesViewController`? When you say "close button" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: ViewController of Metaio...the close button calls - (IBAction)onCloseButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not accelerometer deallocated, it's your view deallocated in between.
Make sure you set .delegate of UIAccelerometer to nil in `dealloc` method of your view.

Comment: So i have to do: UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
accel.delegate = nil;  in viewDidUnload?

Comment: Yes exactly that what you need to do. You can also put it into dealloc method

Comment: I try - (void)viewDidUnload
{
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    UIAccelerometer *accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accel.delegate = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
} but the app crashes again

Comment: RESOLVED WITH - (void) dealloc {
    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:nil];
   
}  thanks